# Typescript interface default that will get overridden in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface that has a property `matchMaker`, it looks like this:

```
export interface ServerOptions {
  matchMaker: MatchMakerType<MatchMaker>
}
```

I then have a class that sets up default values for to utilize that interface which looks like this:

```
export class Server {
  public readonly settings: ServerOptions = {
    matchMaker: undefined
  }

  public constructor(options: ServerOptions) {
    this.settings = Object.assign(this.settings, options)
  }
}
```

When a new instance of the class `Server` is created, I want to require a `typeof MatchMaker` to be set for `matchMaker` when passing the options to the constructor. I don't want to allow `undefined | null` or anything else to be passed to the constructor, however I need to have some value as the default, and when I use `undefined` which will get overridden, I get an error:

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MatchMakerType'.

What can I do to set up a default that will be overridden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Partial`, to allow not defined properties in `Server.settings`:

```
 public readonly settings: Partial<ServerOptions> = {  }
```